# .eml file common e-mail save format

Tags: email, eml

Mozilla Thunderbird can save e-mails as .eml file. Is this a common e-mail format — can all other common e-mail clients open such a file?

Answer (score 0):

MS Outlook I am sure reads them, along with the old outlook express, and I believe the new LiveMail program. Of course, I guess not all email programs necessarily read them, but I would expect the common mail programs to do so.